# Blue Screen Effects Missing in Kdenlive on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kdenlive

I've used **kdenlive** for a few years on Ubuntu 14.04, however, since   migrating to Ubuntu 16.04, my **Blue Screen Effects** are missing in **Alpha Manipulation** selections. I did not try to resolve the issue until now, when I attempted to install *kdenlive anew,* just for this reason on a recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a different machine, however, without success. I could not get **Blue Screen Effects** to appear in the new installation. Does anybody know *what happened with kdenlive* since, or perhaps the switch from **14.04** to **{15,16}.04** requires some additional handling?
  Here is a short summary of how I installed **kdenlive 15.12.03** and the supporting libraries and plugins:

```
1. sudo apt install kdenlive
2. sudo apt install kde-runtime
```

Using *Synaptic* I installed the following items:

```
3. libavformat-dev
4. frei0r-plugins-dev
5. libpulse-dev
6. Gstreamer Tools
```

Running **apt-get install -s gstreamer1.0-libav** I verified **gstreamer1.0-libav** was installed. *It was!*

Any hints of what went wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, by posting a question on **irc.freenode.net#kdenlive**. The bot there found an old answer:

> I believe "Blue screen" was renamed "Chroma key"